# Remove Umbraco's notifications and show my own notifications

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new on Umbraco and I want to remove all Umbraco notifications and show my own notification in my language.
I am trying adding my notifications with this code:

```
angular.module('umbraco').controller('MyController',
function ($scope, notificationsService) {
    notificationsService.success("Exito", "El usuario fue creado exitosamente");          
});
```

But the notification is always showing not matter if is a "success" event or an error event.
Please help me!

Comment: Not sure which language yours is, but you can install/activate a bunch of languages inside Umbraco and set them as default for editors. Are you sure your language isn't already available?

Comment: I would like to use my custom messages, not only my language. Ex.: Digite no mas de 20 caracteres. @JannikAnker

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing works for a custom section you have created, if you want to add a custom message for default messages, you will need to write handler and add it to Umbraco startup class. See example of adding custom message from umbraco forum.

```
using Umbraco.Core;
public class CustomNotificationsRegistration : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    { }

    public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new WebApiHandler());
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
    }
}

using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing;
using Umbraco.Web.UI;
public class WebApiHandler : System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.ToLower() == "/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/content/postsave")
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var response = task.Result;
                    try
                    {
                        var data = response.Content;
                        var content = ((ObjectContent)(data)).Value as ContentItemDisplay;

                        //perform any checking (if needed) to ensure you have the right request
                        //for us the cancellation of publish  was only on one content type so we could narrow that down here 
                        if (content.ContentTypeAlias.Equals("[My content type alias]"))
                        {
                            if (content.Notifications.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var notification in content.Notifications)
                                {
                                    if (notification.Header.Equals("Content Published"))
                                    {
                                        //change the default notification to our custom message
                                        notification.Header = "[Custom Header Message]";
                                        notification.Message = "[Custom Message]";
                                        notification.NotificationType = SpeechBubbleIcon.Sucess;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //log the error
                    }
                    return response;
                });
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Note :** Above is for Content Publish message, if you want it to work for Media `request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.ToLower() == "/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/media/postsave"` should replace request URI from example. and also instead of Publish other criteria can also be checked and replaced.

For detailed discussion see **[umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/developing-umbraco-7-packages/53699-User-Message-(former-Speech-bubble)-in-custom-event)**